# The babel configuration of next.js for the latest browsers

Tags: node.js, babeljs, next.js

The default configuration of Next.js is compatible for IE11. Now we are only writing web app for the latest browsers (the latest version of Edge, Safari, Chrome and Firefox). So we expect babel to do as few things as possible. How can I write the ".babelrc" then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it worth excluding IE11 support since the only polyfill is a global Promise object that makes nextJS work on IE11.

However you can add a custom `.babelrc` to your project. See the documentation here: https://nextjs.org/docs/#customizing-babel-config

and specify the supported browsers using the `preset-env` plugin: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#browserslist-integration

**.babelrc**

```
"presets": [
  ["next/babel", {
    "preset-env": {
      "useBuiltIns": "entry" //tells the preset to look for browserslist config source
    },
  ]
]
```

**package.json**

`"browserslist": "> 0.25%, not dead"`